# How to split results from one field into two separate fields in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, union-all

I am trying top generate a report that gives me the amount of traffic per hour, per lane, per direction.

**The results I'm getting so far:**

```
|TransDate    |Hour  |Lane| Direction| Count|
---------------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  1 |     NB   |  18  |
---------------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  1 |     SB   |  12  |
---------------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  2 |     NB   |  42  |
---------------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  2 |     SB   |  31  |
---------------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  3 |     NB   |   7  |
---------------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  3 |     SB   |   8  |
---------------------------------------------
```

**The results I would like to get:**

```
|TransDate    |Hour  |Lane|  NB  |  SB |
----------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  1 |    18|  12 |
----------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  2 |    42|  31 |
----------------------------------------
|2017-09-05   |1:00  |  3 |     7|   8 |
----------------------------------------
```

My approach so far was to UNION two sets of Code. One set for NB Direction and another set for SB direction.

**My code so far:**

```
SELECT  CAST(TransDT as DATE) as 'TransDate' 
       ,CAST(DATEPART(Hour, TransDT) as varchar) + ':00' as 'Hour' 
       ,LaneID
       ,Direction
       ,COUNT(*) as 'NB_Count'

FROM Traffic_analysis

WHERE cast(TransDT as date) = DATEADD (DAY, -1 , cast(SYSDATETIME() as date))
  AND Direction = 'NB'

GROUP BY CAST(TransDT as DATE), DATEPART(Hour, TransDT), LaneID, Direction
ORDER BY CAST(TransDT as DATE), DATEPART(Hour, TransDT), LaneID, Direction
```

That is obviously not the right approach, because it doesn't work.

What should my approach be so that I get a count for each direction like in the second table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pivot as below:

```
Select * from 
( Select transdate, [hour], lane, direction, [count] from #transdata ) a
pivot (max([count]) for Direction in ([NB],[SB])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+------------+------------------+------+----+----+
| transdate  |       hour       | lane | NB | SB |
+------------+------------------+------+----+----+
| 2017-09-05 | 01:00:00.0000000 |    1 | 18 | 12 |
| 2017-09-05 | 01:00:00.0000000 |    2 | 42 | 31 |
| 2017-09-05 | 01:00:00.0000000 |    3 |  7 |  8 |
+------------+------------------+------+----+----+
```

If you have dynamic list of Direction you can use dynamic query as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Direction) from #transdata  for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @query = '   Select * from 
    ( Select transdate, [hour], lane, direction, [count] from #transdata ) a
    pivot (max([count]) for Direction in (' + @cols1 + ')) p '

Exec sp_executeSql @query
```

Comment: So, do I first Select my data INTO #transdata and then select * from ... ?

Comment: Use your query in subquery

Comment: Kannan.. You are the Boss, matchaa. Thank you very much. This worked.